# Flutter iOS App stuck or fails? What to Do?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, build, flutter-dependencies

What to do when the Flutter app gets stuck on launching or installing dependencies or it fails out of the blue. I have noticed this issue coming up more and more in iOS. Android has its own issues. but a basic flutter upgrade or flutter pub upgrade can cause a lot wastage in developer time as the app will refuse to Build after some of the previously mentioned actions.

Track the list of items one can do to fix the unexpected long build times and build failures

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with flutter for a while and there are few things which I believe can be done to get out of a bad flutter build situation.

Problems being considered
Stuck on flutter clean.
Stuck on flutter run.
Build Failure on Flutter pub upgrade.

The below mentioned solutions were performed and it has solved the problems for me in the past and I very well understand this is not a very clear solution but it still would be worth trying as it solved the issue for me in most cases.

Listing down few of the commands or actions which helped me in solving the issues.

Note: These are mostly related to solving the issues in building on iOS

- flutter upgrade.
- flutter pub cache clean.
- flutter pub cache repair
- flutter clean.
- Deleting .dart_tools
- Deleting Runner.xcworkspace.
- Deleting .symlinks
- Deleting Pods/
- pod deintegrate(inside iOS folder)
- pod cache clean --all.
- pod repo update
- pod update
- pod install

if nothing works then

- update the bundle identifier.
- Delete iOS folder, run flutter create app with the bundle id and copy the iOS folder to project